# What is the Azure Function App Service pricing?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-appservice

In order to create an **Azure Function**, you have to create an **App Service**. I have created an App Service on consomption base.

[image]

In its running state of the App Service, even if i don't execute an Azure Function, do i have to pay something?
I see that `the first 400,000 GB/s of execution and 1,000,000 executions are free in Azure functions` but as **App Service** is a different product, i wanted to be sure. On the other hand, if this App Service is free, why there is a stop button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Consumption Plan, You no longer pay for reserving CPU Cores and RAM of the underlying machine. You only pay for the time your code runs, and not for the time it remains idle.

The stop button is for the FunctionApp itself which can comprise many functions.

But if you choose AppService Plan, The CPU and RAM of the underlying machine still need to be specified as they are reserved for the instance.

Comment: Yes, if you host an Azure Function on an App Service plan, you will pay for the underlying Web App instance on that App Service plan regardless of whether or not the function is running. See here for plan comparisons: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale